# How can I add choices in a Google Form with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to master creating Google Forms programmatically, but can't assign choices to a multiple-choice item. I can create the item (testQuestion) and give it a title, but my createChoice() statements don't add choices.

Here's my code, based on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/page-navigation-type

```
function testCreateChoices() {

/* modification of
  testPageNavigation()
  to see how to import choices from a range on sheet
*/

// Create a form 
var form = FormApp.create('createChoice Test');

// add a multiple-choice item
var testQuestion = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
testQuestion.setTitle('Anything here?');
var whatsis = testQuestion.createChoice('bozzle');
var firstChoice = testQuestion.createChoice('this');
testQuestion.createChoice("that");
testQuestion.createChoice("the other");
testQuestion.createChoice("Ouch!");


//add a new multiple-choice item and a pagebreak item
var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
var pageBreak = form.addPageBreakItem();

// Set some choices with go-to-page logic.
var rightChoice = item.createChoice('Vanilla', FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);
var wrongChoice = item.createChoice('Chocolate', FormApp.PageNavigationType.RESTART);

// For GO_TO_PAGE, just pass in the page break item. For CONTINUE (normally the default), pass in
// CONTINUE explicitly because page navigation cannot be mixed with non-navigation choices.
var iffyChoice = item.createChoice('Peanut', pageBreak);
var otherChoice = item.createChoice('Strawberry', FormApp.PageNavigatio[enter image description here][1]nType.CONTINUE);
item.setChoices([rightChoice, wrongChoice, iffyChoice, otherChoice]);
  
}
```

Here's what I get, with the choices "bozzle" and so on not displayed, and an image of what I want but can't create.

Many thanks for any help!

[Here's a screenshot, with no labels/choices under "Anything here?"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXPup.jpg)

[And a mockup with "bozzle", "this" and so on as choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klIt6.jpg)

Comment: What exactly do you mean that you cannot add the choices? If I run the code you've shared, I am able to successfully see the options. Would you mind sharing a screenshot of the desired result as well?

Comment: I've edited the question, adding screenshots. When you run the c code, do you see the intended choices under "Anything here?" I recopied the code from the post, and still got no labels under that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The reason you are not seeing the options for the `testQuestion` is because you didn't set the choices for the question.**

Therefore, I suggest you update the bit where you create your first question to this:

```
var testQuestion = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
testQuestion.setChoices([testQuestion.createChoice('bozzle'), testQuestion.createChoice('this'), testQuestion.createChoice("that"), testQuestion.createChoice("the other"), testQuestion.createChoice("Ouch!")]);
```

The `createChoice` method is used to create the choice items only and in order to actually add them to the question, you have to use the `setChoices` method as well.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Class MultipleChoiceItem - createChoice(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createchoicevalue);
- [Apps Script Class MultipleChoiceItem - setChoices(Choice)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#setchoiceschoices).

Comment: Many thanks! I should have figured out for myself that there wouldn't be a setChoices() method if all you needed was createChoice(). ;<)